# How do I get user id in my component to be able to dispatch to the action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I want to show user feed and his posts. I'm planning to dispatch an action from componentDidMount of the UserPosts component but don't have the id now. The component looks like this:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { getUserposts } from "../actions/userActions"

class UserPosts extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    //////
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="card">
        <div className="card-content">
          <div className="media">
            <div className="media-left">
              <figure className="image is-48x48">
                <img
                  src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/96x96.png"
                  alt="Placeholder image"
                />
              </figure>
            </div>
            <div className="media-content">
              <p className="title is-4"></p>
              <p className="subtitle is-6"></p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="content">Insert Bio</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default UserPosts
```

and the action like this:

```js
export const getUserposts = (id) => {
    return async dispatch => {
      dispatch({
        type: "FETCHING_POSTS",
      })
      try {
        const res = await axios.get(
          `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/posts/${id}`, {
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
          }
        )
        dispatch({
          type: "FETCHING_POSTS_SUCCESS",
          data: res.data
        })
      } catch(err) {
        dispatch({
          type: "FETCHING_POSTS_ERROR",
          data: { error: res.data.error}
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

Now how do i get the id? I have a route that gives me the current logged in user. It's the `/me` route. I have set up on top of my `App.js`, so it runs on every refresh. So, is it possible to first dispatch for the `/me` route, grab the id, and then dispatch again for the `getUserPosts` action. How do I dispatch two actions from the componentDidMount?

Is this feasible.

```js
componentDidMount() {
   const authToken = localStorage.getItem("authToken");
   this.props.dipsatch(getCurrentUser(authToken)) // this will return the current user object
   this.props.dispatch(getUserPosts(id)) // i will probably get this id from the props from the 
                                            //redux store
}

Please tell how can I approach this? Thanks.
```

Comment: Is this an id for some "logged in" user? If so, then presumably you've already stored that in app state and can use it in any other component connected to your store. Dispatched actions are just functions, you can call as many as you need pretty much whenever (*when connected to redux*).

Comment: Yes, it's the id of the logged in user. How do I call multiple actions in `componentDidMount`? I've seen different practices. Some use `Promise.all` and some other. Idk which is right or wrong.

Comment: Promises aren't related to redux actions at all. And `Promise.all` **definitely** wouldn't help you solve your issue of needing *some* data from the *first* function to pass to the *second*.